# cpu frequency reported values

Tags: power-management, cpu-frequency

I have a 4 socket server, running E5-4667v3.  I have the power profile set to *performance low-latency*.

For reference: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/85765/intel-xeon-processor-e5-4667-v3-40m-cache-2-00-ghz.html

Per Intel it's **Base Frequency is 2.0 GHz** and **Max Turbo Frequency is 2.9 GHz**.

- in SLES 11.4 a `cat /proc/cpuinfo` shows `cpu MHz: 2001.000` when completely idle or fully loaded.
- in SLES 11.4 a `dmidecode -t 4` shows `Max Speed: 3600 MHz`
- in SLES 11.4 a `lscpu` shows `CPU MHz: 2001.000`
- in RHEL 7.6 a `cat /proc/cpuinfo` shows values all around `3200` on 60 cores when an indentical system is crunching.
- I have to get back to my rhel 7.6 system to get more numbers to see what's reported when completely idle.

I got some info from here:
[What is the correct way to view your CPU speed on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264632/what-is-the-correct-way-to-view-your-cpu-speed-on-linux)

Is `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu MHz"` a solid way to see the correct cpu operating frequency at a given moment?  What is?  For my RHEL 7.6 system, that's been running 100% for > 24 hours and I check cpu frequency and it's well above the published turbo frequency?  I thought turbo frequency was temporary?  If I kick off a MPI based job and say run on 60 of 64 total cores, how long should I expect cores to run above base frequency?

Comment: See an answer by @WinEunuuchs2Unix on the related post you provided. /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq should be the most accurate, as long as you have a cpufreq driver running (you should have).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to view your CPU speed on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264632/what-is-the-correct-way-to-view-your-cpu-speed-on-linux)

Comment: You can [look at some CPU counters to compute the current real CPU frequency](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582475/1131).